# Upload multiple executables for different OS versions

Tags: app-store, mac-app-store

Can we upload multiple ".app" files, each for a different OS versions, for example for version 10.7 I have a different applicaiton build with features supported only in 10.7 and later, and  for 10.8 a different applicaiton which has features supported by 1.8 and later ??
My next question if it is possible than is Mac App store application smart enough to give user that version depending on his/her OS version(if use has 10.7 than download 10.7 version of app and if user has 10.8 than download 10.8 version of app on users machine) ??
Is the similar is availble for iOS(like for example iOS 6 and iOS 5 etc) ??
If not than does Apple has any plans to implement these features in their iOS and Mac app stores ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

You're really meant to do this dynamically. For example you can weakly link frameworks and test for a particular objc class's existence.

```
gcc -weak_framework AVFoundation source.m

if (NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureSession")) {
  // do stuff with AVFoundation here
}
```

You can also test to see if particular objects respond to the selector you would like to use.

```
if ([myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(selectorYouWantToUse:)]) {
  [myObject selectorYouWantToUse:@"indeed"];
}
```

Sometimes neither of these do the right thing, in which case you can examine the file at

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

I find it useful to wrap this in a function with the signature

```
bool macOSXVersionIsAtleast(int major, int minor, int bugfix);
```

(implementation left to the reader).